# saving several plots contained within a list as one pdf file with ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2

I save several plots in a list as one file using `ggsave`. I recently did an update to `ggplot2` and my function has stopped working. Please could someone help me.

My code that is not working is as follows (however this used to work before):

```
library(tidyverse)

plot_1 <- cars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(speed, dist)) + geom_line()
    
plot_2 <- cars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(dist, speed)) + geom_line()

   
ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "myplot.pdf",
                plot = map(list(plot_1, plot_2), print),
                device = "pdf")
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52902877/786542

Comment: @Tung I have several files that save using the above code. Any idea why the code stopped working? I was hoping for a quick fix. My other alternative is to use `pdf` but this will take time, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

To print multiple plots in the same pdf this works for me.

```
ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "myplot.pdf",
                plot = gridExtra::marrangeGrob(list(plot_1, plot_2), nrow = 1, ncol = 1), 
                device = "pdf")
```